# Adding characters in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How to write same method in characters if it is in strings.For example Increase method given below.

```
 String a;

 public boolean increase(String b){

 if(a.length() >0)
 this.a = this.a + b;

return true
}
```

I want to write same method something like.

```
String a ;
char[] achar = a.tochararray()

public boolean increase(String b){
char[] bchar = b.tochararray();
if(a.length() >0){
for(i =0; i < a.length();i++){
achar[i] = achar[i] + bchar[i];
}
achar[i] = achar[i] + bchar[i];
return true;
}
```

If String a = "Concat", String b = "Method".
if true;
output be like: Concat Method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you asking for.

```
if( a.equals("Contact") && b.equals("Method") )
{
    String wholeSentance = a + " " + b;
    char[] sentanceInCharArray = wholeSentance.toCharArray();
}
```